# LowLevelKeyboardProc - No overload macthes delegate

Tags: c#, keystroke

Before I explain my error, know that I don't understand it all myself, its mostly from a tutorial, but thought I'd post it on here just in case anyone knows. So this is used to get each keystroke. These are my variables:

```cs
#region Key Strokes
private const int WM_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, UIntPtr lParam);
private static byte CapsLock = 0;
private static byte Shift = 0;
private static IntPtr HookID = IntPtr.Zero;
private static LowLevelKeyboardProc Proc = GetKeyStrokes;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lparam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadID);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
#endregion
```

In my main function, I set the `HookID`:

```cs
HookID = SetHook(Proc);
```

I then have my `SetHook` function:

```cs
private static IntPtr SetHook (LowLevelKeyboardProc Proc)
{
    using (Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
    using (ProcessModule m = p.MainModule)
        return SetWindowsHookEx(WM_KEYBOARD_LL, Proc, GetModuleHandle(m.ModuleName), 0);
}
```

And then lastly, I have my `GetKeyStrokes` function:

```cs
private static IntPtr GetKeyStrokes(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        int Code = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
        if(Keys.Shift == Control.ModifierKeys)
        {
            Program.Shift = 1;
        }
        //Switch statment for special keys(too long)
        }
        Program.Shift = 0;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(HookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The only error I get is with my variable `Proc = GetKeyStrokes;` which says

> No overload for "GetKeyStrokes" matches delegate "Program.LowLevelKeyboardProc".

I know this is pretty complex, and I'm not expecting many people to get it, I don't even get a lot of it, but any ideas are welcome, thanks.

Comment: `private static IntPtr GetKeyStrokes(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)` - change last param type to `UIntPtr`. Delegate and function must have same signature.

Comment: that threw up another error so i just declared lparam as IntPtr instead of UIntPtr and it worked, wouldnt have seen that if u didnt point it out first, thanks alot :) much appriciated

Comment: Not the only problem, that delegate object is going to get garbage-collected and then your program dies.  Don't write this yourself, use a library.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah, it should be pinned and released after GC. But he said this is tutorial and I have doubts that this code will go to production .